# Ruby on rails - how to retrieve connection strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Are there any ways to retrieve the database connection string where my ruby is connected? what i would like to get is the:

1) Database name where the ruby is connected
2) The username of the SQL Server
3) Password of the SQL Server
4) Server name

I want to store it in session variables.

(I'am using MS SQL Server.)

Please help! thanks!

Comment: I'm not even going to ask why you would want to store these in session variables. Ok. Why do you want to store these in a session?

Comment: because i need to call a CGI application, and this CGI needs to connect to database where my ruby is connected. take note that every client has different connection strings, so the connection string of the CGI application should be dynamic depending on the ruby connection string. hope you can help me with this one. thanks

Answer (score 15):

I would go with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` which returns hash with options for ActiveRecord 3.

Answer (score 7):

You can access all of the properties described in your database.yaml like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["development"] => 
{"encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"foo", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"bar_development", "host"=>"localhost", "password"=> "baz"}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I needed to write a rake task that mysqldump'ed our production database, and didn't want to have to hard-code the connection strings outside the database.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Database: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database`

You could also do some fancy Regexs with the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.inspect
```

But yeah, this is a terrible idea.

Comment: using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.inspect does show the username and password but i' am having problems in regexs, i cannot get just let say the password only

Answer (score 0):

These values are all stored in the file `config/database.yml`, but AFAIK you can't access these values as variables from within your controller.

Comment: Your app could read/interpret the config/database.yml file. It'd then have all of the info to do with as it wished.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `connection_db_config` which returns `ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::UrlConfig` object, which looks like this

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config
=> #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::UrlConfig:0x000055794c915ad0
 @configuration_hash=
  {:adapter=>"postgresql",
   :encoding=>"unicode",
   :pool=>5,
   :username=>"postgres",
   :password=>nil,
   :host=>"localhost",
   :port=>5432,
   :database=>"oyster_development"},
 @env_name="development",
 @name="primary",
 @url="postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432">
```

Calling `url` will give you connection URL:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.url
=> "postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432"
```

You can append it with database name, to get (what I believe) is a full connection string

```
> "#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.url}/#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.database}"
=> "postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/your_project_development"
```